# jQuery: animated, continuous loop through children

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

Close but not quite there. I'd like to have the first child div displayed for a couple seconds, slide down (via positioning) and fade out of view, then the next child slide up and fade into view.  Repeat continuously, looping back after the last child is displayed.

Looks like I've got the loop working though the count seems to pile the child divs on top of each other.  What am I doing wrong?

**http://jsfiddle.net/rrbaker/Xmk2y/4/**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my remix: http://jsfiddle.net/ddrace/DJuV7/1/

I rearranged some things to make it more understandable and added settings for the pause and animation to keep it DRY and easier to tweak.

Comment: nice one. This looks much useful and gives reader enough time to read.

Answer (score 2):

Does this look ok 
http://jsfiddle.net/Xmk2y/5/

I removed the delay , set i = 0 and swapped top values.

Comment: That's it. Knew I needed a second pair of eyes on those variables, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/Quincy/Xmk2y/8/

Just using the `complete` callback to recursively invoke `nextQuote`

Comment: That definitely does the trick; working like I wanted it to now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems there were a few issues according to what you had mentioned. First was setting the index to -1. That seemed to cause the display all issue. Next was the animations, i have updated it to use jquery promises to ensure that the animation of the previous was finished.

End result: http://jsfiddle.net/bfbuS/2/

jQuery Promise: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: +1 for Promise. Although personally, I think I prefer it when the animations overlap a bit.

Comment: sure sometimes it makes sense, i was just trying to follow the stated intent.

Comment: Did not know about promise, thank you for having a look and that tip. So much better than putting in delay() shims.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works too: http://jsfiddle.net/Xmk2y/7/. But I think I like Birey's solution better.