# animate each child jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

It's amazing how simple this should be but I can't get it to work. I'm looking to animate a set of divs one at a time. I am using animate.css for those familiar with it. I thought I may have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962244/jquery-animated-continuous-loop-through-children) but jsFiddle is not working at the moment. Anywho, the code is

`$('.elements').each(function(i)
{
        $(this).addClass('animated slideInLeft').delay(500);
    });`

The problem is that when I debug and step through each element, the animation is happening for each element but when I let it run, it appears to all do it at once. What is needed to actually show the animation one at a time?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

jsFiddle is back up and that link provided below did not help. The answer did not include looping through elements, but looping the animation itself.

**EDIT 2**

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSwbz/) to play with if you guys need one.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for your project we could play with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.elements').each(function(i) {
   delay =(i)*500;
   $(this).delay(delay).animate({
       opacity:1
    }, {
    duration: 500,
    complete: function() {
       $(this).addClass('animated slideInLeft');
    }
  });  
});
```

Edit: I moved the `addClass` to the complete property

Can you try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KSwbz/8/) as well:

```
$('.element').hide()

$('.element').each(function(i) {
   delay =(i)*500;
   setTimeout(function (div) {
            div.show().addClass('animated slideInLeft');
        }, delay, $(this));
});
```

Comment: @Rachid I tried this variation as well. For some reason it doesn't work. I provided a Fiddle above.

Comment: Still sliding in all at once :-/

Comment: Some how I was able to edit [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DJuV7/53/). It's working there

Comment: @Rachid I am very sorry about the confusion! I meant using the fiddle under my edit #2. That one is my scenario built by me. Sorry again.

Comment: No apology is necessary. I've updated the code and the fiddle link above as well. which should work per my test

Comment: @Rachid that fiddle is the wrong one. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/KSwbz/) link is my scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I have some tweaking to do but you have really given me a great answer to continue!

Comment: @Rachid if I may ask, do you know why the divs show in their spots before sliding in? I assumed they would just slide in without already being placed beforehand.

Comment: It because, we're setting to `opacity:1` one first which displays the element and once the animate event is complete we are adding the `animated slideInLeft` which caused the element to hide and slide from the left. This can be addressed. I'll try to post an update if I get the chance

Comment: Great, thanks! Meanwhile, I'm trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: You've been a big help! That is perfect! Thanks!