# How to Animate jQuery collection items individually

Tags: jquery, animation

Animating a jQuery collection of objects seems to animate them all together, as a group, rather than individually.

I have a few DIVs inside a container div and wish to animate them to slide into view sequentially, like a carousel.

This happens whether I use `$.each()` method:

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/br0d1tcn)

or a `for` loop:

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/br0d1tcn/1/)

I am guessing that is because: the objects are individually animated but the loop does not wait for one animation to finish before beginning the next. The animations are started sequentially, within a few ms of one another, and overlap in their progression.

How can that be fixed?

I tried adding a delay [as recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597735/animate-each-child-jquery), but the result is not ideal.

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/br0d1tcn/2/)

There must be a better way. *Just a WAG: perhaps by using the Promises interface?*

```js
$('.slide').each(function(){
 $(this).animate({
  left : 0
 },1500);
});

/*
for (var n=0; n < $('.slide').length; n++){
 $($('.slide')[n]).animate({
  left: 0
 },1500);
}
*/

/*
$('.slide').each(function(i){
 d =(i)*500;
 $(this).delay(d).animate({
  left : 0
 },1500);
});
*/
```

```css
#slideshow{position:relative;width:100%;height:200px;overflow:hidden;}
.slide{position:absolute;top:0;left:100%;width:100%;height:100%;}
img{width:100%;height:100%;}
#s1{background-color:pink;}
#s2{background-color:palegreen;}
#s3{background-color:wheat;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
 <div id="s1" class="slide">
  <h2>Slide One</h2>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/150" />
 </div>
 <div id="s2" class="slide">
  <h2>Slide Two</h2>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/502/150" />
 </div>
 <div id="s3" class="slide">
  <h2>Slide Three</h2>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/498/150" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `delay()` should be enough.

Comment: `for` loops and `each` (whcih is just an alias for a loop) are synchronous, so to all intents and purposes you're starting all the animations at the same time. What's "not ideal" about delay? You said you wanted a sequential animation and the delay example delivers that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at below approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/br0d1tcn/5/

Here we are calling a animate function for each slide one by one:

```
var totalLength = $('.slide').length;
if (totalLength > 0) {
  animateSlides(0);
}

function animateSlides(n) {
  $($('.slide')[n]).animate({
    left: 0
  }, 1500, function() {
    if (n < totalLength - 1) {
      n++;
      animateSlides(n);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: That's really nice, clever use of the "complete" function.

Comment: Great answer, Vijay. Thanks, +1 and check. I was trying to use this method to create a quick n dirty carousel, but it turned out to be rather complex. If interested, [here's where I finally threw in towel.](https://jsfiddle.net/mvwndnv4/) If you can get it to repeat, add solution in another answer and I'll upvote that also.

Comment: @gibberish, please have a look at another answer which i have added. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Had a great fun making the carousel repeat after the end of last slide. Please have a look at updated fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/mvwndnv4/8/

Hope that's what you are looking for:

```js
$('body').css({
  'background-color': 'lightblue'
});
var loop = 1;
var arr = [3, 1, 2];
var totalLength = $('.slide').length;
if (totalLength > 0) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    animateSlides(0)
  }, 3000);
}

function animateSlides(n) {

  if (n + 1 == totalLength) {
    $($('.slide')[0]).animate({
      left: 0
    }, 1500, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        animateSlides(0);
      }, 3000);
    });
  } else {
    $($('.slide')[n + 1]).animate({
      left: 0
    }, 1500, function() {

    });
  }

  $($('.slide')[n]).animate({
    left: '-100%'
  }, 1500, function() {

    $(this).css({
      'left': '100%'
    });
    if (n == totalLength - 1) {

    } else {
      n++;
      setTimeout(function() {
        animateSlides(n);
      }, 3000);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  XXoverflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide:not(:first-of-type) {
  left: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#s1 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#s2 {
  background-color: palegreen;
}

#s3 {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slideshow">
  <div id="s1" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide One</h2>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/150" />
  </div>
  <div id="s2" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide Two</h2>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/502/150" />
  </div>
  <div id="s3" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide Three</h2>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/498/150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, we need to switch scores -- that is excellent. Well done +1

Comment: I will study your other answers on SO, upvoting as appropriate.